# Dynamic use of offsets excel

Tags: excel, dynamic, offset

I got a problem about the use of offset functions in excel. Basically I got two col of consideration: First I need the calculation in col AD, so: AD = AA + AG_(+1). With AG_(+1) I mean the next coming value in col AG. Similarly I need the following calculation in col AF: AF = R + M_(-1), where M_(-1) means the previous value in col M.

Now this would be straight forward if I had values in all rows, this is however not the case. I have tons of blanks in my 6000+ rows which complicates matters for me.

I reckon you can use the offset functions, but I cant seem to get it right. Any suggestions?

A small dummy example is seen below:

[image]

Best

Comment: What do you need exactly ?

Comment: @matzone I need to get formulas for col AD and col AF. So AD = AA + AG_+1. However the value in AG could be 100 rows below AD and AA. The gap varies a lot.

Comment: If you create formula and you copy other columns below .. it works isn't it ?

Comment: Kind of. So far I have made a formula =AA2+OFFSET(AG2;MATCH(1;AG3:AG1000;0);0). The combination of offset and match finds the next value of AG, but I does it in every row. I only need the calculation if AA also has a value

Comment: And =IF(AA2 <> 0; AA2+OFFSET(AG2;MATCH(1;AG3:AG1000;0);0;"")) returns false when needed but #Value! when where should be a result

Comment: also start with `=IF(AA2 <> 0,AA2+OFFSET(AG2,MATCH(1,AG3:AG1000,0),0,""))`

Comment: @glh I have attached an small example. This is not the actual data. Im not sure, that I kan use the match function this way after all. The code I wrote earlier only works if AG = 1, which is not the case most of the time

Comment: @pnuts Sorry - I gave all of you a wrong starting point. The match formula is wrong implemented. I have attached a picture of the problem in the description

Comment: @pnuts why does you comment look like a winking pig? ;)

Comment: @pnuts true but what is the context? we cant say... defiantly flatten or copy the data up or down if possible

Comment: @pnuts Do you have any suggestions for this problem?

Comment: @pnuts there's nothing I can see wrong with my code. It tested fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a combination of an array formula, relative referencing and the if, index, row and min formulas you'll get a costly but sufficient result.

My test data:

[image]

And the formula added in `B1` to get the cell down:

```
{=IF(A1="","",A1 + INDEX($C$1:$C$20,MIN(IF(C1:$C$20="",9999,1)*ROW(C1:$C$20))))}
```

Explanation:

1. `IF(C1:$C$20="",9999,1)` find the cells not blank **note: you'll have to alter the 9999 to get your true outer limits** or change to `ROWS(C:C)+1`
2. `MIN(IF(...)*ROW(C1:$C$20))` get the first non blank row
3. `INDEX($C$1:$C$16,MIN(...))` get the value on the first non blank
4. `IF(A1="","",...` will remove leave blank if an cells to the left are blank

And the formula added in `B6` to get the cell up:

```
{=A6 + INDEX($C$1:C6,MAX(IF($C$1:C6="",0,1)*ROW($C$1:C6)))}
```

Comment: It's an array formula.  Did you enter it with control + shift + enter to submit it? That's what I meant by the {}.

Comment: Ohh.. Never heard of that. Anyway control + enter and control + shift + enter is not working either. I cant submit it

Comment: Dont type in the {} and press control + shift + enter. This tested fine for me as the image shows. You may need to tweak some cell references to get it into your scenario

Comment: Ohh.. Never heard of that. Anyway control + enter and control + shift + enter is not working either. That means I can get 8, if I use your example in B1, but in B6 its not working

Comment: If you copy the cell b1 and paste it in b6 the relative reference will keep. A1 will change to a6 and c1 to c6

Comment: Yup.. But I get the value 3 in B6. But the references is just as you described

Comment: nice catch. I didn't completely test :) caught me out!

Comment: @glh Now its good.. What about if you need to go cells up. Will this do the trick: {=A6 + INDEX($C$1:C6,MAX(IF($C$1:C6="",0,1)*ROW($C$1:C6)))}

Comment: @roarknuppel yeah. please let me know if not

Comment: @glh Is a way so I dont get all the value between the ones Im interested in. In your example that would be B2:B5 etc

Comment: @glh You might have got a bit of stick, but its working. Both ways.. Cheers mate!